# Circle in $\mathbb{S}^3$ not mapping to a point in $\mathbb{S}^2$ under Hopf map

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, quaternions, hopf-fibration

The Hopf fibration is a mapping $h:\mathbb{S^3} \mapsto\mathbb{S}^2$ defined by $r\mapsto ri\bar{r}$ where $r$ is a unit quaternion in the form $r=a+bi+cj+dk $ where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$  and $ijk=-1$. Explicitly, $$h(a,b,c,d)=(a^2+c^2-b^2+d^2,2(ad+bc),2(bd-ac))$$ Now, it is known that for a point in $\mathbb{S^2}$ the preimage $h^{-1}$ is a circle in $\mathbb{S^3}$. How can this be? If you consider the set of points $$C= \{(\cos(t),0,0,\sin(t)) \mid t\in\mathbb{R}\} \in \mathbb{S^3}$$ which can be written in terms of quaternions as $C=e^{k t}$ where $ t \in \mathbb{R}$. This clearly doesn't map to a single point in  $\mathbb{S^2}$ under the Hopf fibration. It maps to the circle $i\cos(2t)+j\sin(2t)$. So I am not understanding what's going on here. Why is this circle on in 4 dimensional space not mapping to a point in 3 dimensional space?

Comment: The claim is not that every circle maps to a point, just that every point is mapped to by some circle.

Comment: The fibers of a function partition the domain. You can stereographically project $S^3$ to $\Bbb R^3$ and visualize the fibers as a collection of circles (which form nested tori), with the proviso that the circle through the point of projection in $S^3$ becomes a line in $\Bbb R^3$, by image searching Hopf fibration or Hopf bundle.

Comment: Your question has marked similarities to [my own post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4260297/152225) this weekend, and I wonder if you could sketch an answer to it, since you probably have been able to make some progress based on other interesting questions you have on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

As Cheerful Parsnip explained in his comment, the claim is not that every circle maps to a point, but that all preimages of points are circles.

A simple example illustrating this is the projection $p : S^2 \times S^1  \to S^2$. All preimages of points are $1$-spheres, but of course not every image of a $1$-sphere in $S^2 \times S^1$ is a point. Take for example the equator $E \subset S^2$. Then $E \times \{1\}$ is a $1$-sphere, but its image is $E$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

The unit quaternion $\hat{\Psi}$ in the SO(3) picture.
\begin{equation} 
\hat{\Psi}\;=\; 
\begin{pmatrix}
q_1^2+q_i^2-q_j^2-q_k^2 & 2(q_iq_j-q_1q_k) & 2(q_iq_k+q_1q_j) \\
2(q_iq_j+q_1q_k) & q_1^2-q_i^2+q_j^2-q_k^2 & 2(q_jq_k-q_1q_i) \\
2(q_iq_k-q_1q_j) & 2(q_jq_k+q_1q_i) & q_1^2-q_i^2-q_j^2+q_k^2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
We can label the elements as:
\begin{equation*}
\hat{\Psi}\;=\;
\begin{pmatrix}
 \mathcal{I}^i_{l} & \mathcal{I}^j_{l} & \mathcal{I}^k_{l} \\
 \mathcal{J}^i_{l} & \mathcal{J}^j_{l} & \mathcal{J}^k_{l} \\
 \mathcal{K}^i_{l} & \mathcal{K}^j_{l} & \mathcal{K}^k_{l} 
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\hat{\Psi}\;=\;
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathcal{I}^i_{r} & \mathcal{J}^i_{r} & \mathcal{K}^i_{r} \\
\mathcal{I}^j_{r} & \mathcal{J}^j_{r} & \mathcal{K}^j_{r} \\
\mathcal{I}^k_{r} & \mathcal{J}^k_{r} & \mathcal{K}^k_{r} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

The Lie algebra matrices defined by
\begin{equation} 
 \hat{\pi}_i\;\equiv\; 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
  0 & 0 & -1 \\ 
  0 & 1 & 0 
 \end{pmatrix}\qquad 
 \hat{\pi}_j\;\equiv\; 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
  0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
  -1 & 0 & 0 
 \end{pmatrix}\qquad 
 \hat{\pi}_k\;\equiv\; 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
  1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
  0 & 0 & 0 
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
For a quaternion $\hat{\Psi}$ there are 6 possible mappings from $\mathbb{S}^3\mapsto\mathbb{S}^2$, given by
\begin{align}
\hat{\mathcal{I}}_l\;=\;\hat{\Psi}^t\hat{\pi}_i\hat{\Psi}
\qquad\qquad\;\;
\hat{\mathcal{J}}_l\;&=\;\hat{\Psi}^t\hat{\pi}_j\hat{\Psi}
\qquad\qquad\;
\hat{\mathcal{K}}_l\;=\;\hat{\Psi}^t\hat{\pi}_k\hat{\Psi} \\ 
\hat{\mathcal{I}}_r\;=\;\hat{\Psi}\hat{\pi}_i\hat{\Psi}^t
\;\qquad\qquad
\hat{\mathcal{J}}_r\;&=\;\hat{\Psi}\hat{\pi}_j\hat{\Psi}^t
\qquad\qquad\;
\hat{\mathcal{K}}_r\;=\;\hat{\Psi}\hat{\pi}_k\hat{\Psi}^t 
\end{align}

To rotate a quaternion in $\mathbb{R}^4$, consider the basis matrices:

The left Cayley matrices:
\begin{equation}
\hat{l}_i\;=\; 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\;\;\;\;
\hat{l}_j\;=\; 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\;\;\;\;
\hat{l}_k\;=\; 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
which satisfy the relation
$$\hat{l}_i^2\;=\;\hat{l}_j^2\;=\;\hat{l}_k^2\;=\;\hat{l}_i\hat{l}_j\hat{l}_k\;=\;-\hat{l}_1$$
The right Cayley matrices:
\begin{equation}
\hat{r}_i\;=\; 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\;\;\;\;
\hat{r}_j\;=\; 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\;\;\;\;
\hat{r}_k\;=\; 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
which satisfy the relation
$$\hat{r}_i^2\;=\;\hat{r}_j^2\;=\;\hat{r}_k^2\;=\;\hat{r}_i\hat{r}_j\hat{r}_k\;=\;-\hat{r}_1$$
and $\hat{l}_1,\hat{r}_1$ are the $4\times4$ identity matrices.

In vector form the quaternion is represented
\begin{equation*}
\vec{\Psi}\;=\;
\begin{pmatrix}
q_1 \\
q_i \\
q_j \\
q_k 
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation*}
Rotate the quaternion $\vec{\Psi}$ in the left Cayley basis, through an angle $\varphi$ in the $\hat{l}_i$ axis.
$$\vec{\Psi}'\;=\;\exp\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\hat{l}_i\right)\vec{\Psi}$$
\begin{equation}
\vec{\Psi}'\;=\;
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\left(\tfrac{\varphi}{2}\right) & -\sin\left(\tfrac{\varphi}{2}\right) & 0 & 0 \\ 
\sin\left(\tfrac{\varphi}{2}\right) & \cos\left(\tfrac{\varphi}{2}\right) & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & \cos\left(\tfrac{\varphi}{2}\right) & -\sin\left(\tfrac{\varphi}{2}\right) \\
0 & 0 & \sin\left(\tfrac{\varphi}{2}\right) & \cos\left(\tfrac{\varphi}{2}\right) 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
q_1 \\
q_i \\
q_j \\
q_k 
\end{pmatrix}
\;=\; 
\begin{pmatrix}
 \cos\left(\tfrac{\varphi}{2}\right)q_1-q_i\sin\left(\tfrac{\varphi}{2}\right) \\ 
 \cos\left(\tfrac{\varphi}{2}\right)q_i+q_1\sin\left(\tfrac{\varphi}{2}\right) \\ 
 \cos\left(\tfrac{\varphi}{2}\right)q_j-q_k\sin\left(\tfrac{\varphi}{2}\right) \\ 
 \cos\left(\tfrac{\varphi}{2}\right)q_k+q_j\sin\left(\tfrac{\varphi}{2}\right)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
By extension - the quaternion can be rotated in a circle in $\mathbb{R}^4$ using the 6 rotation axes $\hat{l}_i,\hat{l}_j,\hat{l}_k,\hat{r}_i,\hat{r}_j,\hat{r}_k$.

$\vec{\Psi}'$ in the SO(3) picture:
\begin{equation*}
\hat{\Psi}'\;=\; 
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathcal{I}^i_{l} & \mathcal{I}^j_{l} & \mathcal{I}^k_{l} \\
\mathcal{J}^i_{l}\cos(\varphi) - \mathcal{K}^i_{l}\sin(\varphi) & 
\mathcal{J}^j_{l}\cos(\varphi) - \mathcal{K}^j_{l}\sin(\varphi) & 
\mathcal{J}^k_{l}\cos(\varphi) - \mathcal{K}^k_{l}\sin(\varphi) \\
\mathcal{K}^i_{l}\cos(\varphi) + \mathcal{J}^i_{l}\sin(\varphi) & 
\mathcal{K}^j_{l}\cos(\varphi) + \mathcal{J}^j_{l}\sin(\varphi) & 
\mathcal{K}^k_{l}\cos(\varphi) + \mathcal{J}^k_{l}\sin(\varphi)
\end{pmatrix}\\
\end{equation*}
where $\varphi\in[0,4\pi]$.

Now to your question:

**Why is this circle on in 4 dimensional space not mapping to a point in 3 dimensional space?**

The circle in $\mathbb{R}^4$,is projected to a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ via:
\begin{equation*}
\hat{\mathcal{I}}_l\;=\;\hat{\Psi}^t\hat{\pi}_i\hat{\Psi}
\;=\;\hat{\Psi}'^t\hat{\pi}_i\hat{\Psi}'
\end{equation*}

To view the fibre in the traditional form, consider the stereographic projection of the quaternion via the mapping:
\begin{equation*}
 \mathbb{S}^3/(1,0,0,0)\;\mapsto\;\mathbb{R}^3
\end{equation*}
given by
\begin{equation} 
 (q_1',q_i',q_j',q_k')\;\mapsto\;\left(\frac{q_i'}{1-q_1'},\frac{q_j'}{1-q_1'},\frac{q_k'}{1-q_1'}\right)
\end{equation}
with $\varphi\in[0,4\pi]$.

Comment: reference is:
[arxiv.org/abs/1601.02569](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.02569)